# How to put an array in a item of RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to put an array of names(NomUser) in the first item of the RecyclerView. So I know I need to change the String of the constructor putting String[] but then how I can put the information when I do a new PendingTrajectPOJO?

[I want the names of Joan and Ousmane on the first item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KghHj.png)

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2dRy.png)

Here is where I put the information

```
 listPendingTraject.add(new PendingTrajectPOJO(nomUser,"Surname","Origin","Destination",Data));

    adapter = new AdapterPendingTraject(listPendingTraject);
    recyclerPendingTraject.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is my constructor

```
public PendingTrajectPOJO(String name, String surName, String origin, String destination, String date) {
    Name = name;
    SurName = surName;
    Origin = origin;
    Destination = destination;
    Date = date;
}
```

My adapter

```
public class AdapterPendingTraject extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterPendingTraject.ViewHolderPendingTraject>{

ArrayList<PendingTrajectPOJO> listPendingTraject;

public AdapterPendingTraject(ArrayList<PendingTrajectPOJO> listPendingTraject) {
    this.listPendingTraject = listPendingTraject;
}

@Override
public ViewHolderPendingTraject onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.pending_traject_item,null,false);
    return new ViewHolderPendingTraject(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderPendingTraject holder, int position) {
    holder.Name.setText(listPendingTraject.get(position).getName());
    holder.Surname.setText(listPendingTraject.get(position).getSurName());
    holder.Origin.setText(listPendingTraject.get(position).getOrigin());
    holder.Destination.setText(listPendingTraject.get(position).getDestination());
    holder.Date.setText(listPendingTraject.get(position).getDate());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Journey.class);
            //intent.putExtra("FileName", list.get(position));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listPendingTraject.size();
}

public class ViewHolderPendingTraject extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView Name,Surname,Origin,Destination,Date;
    public ViewHolderPendingTraject(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvptName);
        Surname=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvptSurName);
        Origin=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvptOrigin);
        Destination=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvptDestination);
        Date=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvptDate);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is create a public method in your adapter to pass in a new item. In this method, you need to notify the adapter that you have updated the items. I would recommend using the DiffUtil to find out which items have changed like this:

```
public void addNewItem(PendingTrajectPOJO p) {
    ArrayList<PendingTrajectPOJO> old = new ArrayList<PendingTrajectPOJO>(listPendingTraject)

    this.listPendingTraject = new ArrayList<PendingTrajectPOJO>()
    this.listPendingTraject.add(p)
    this.listPendingTraject.addAll(old)

    DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new MyDiffCallback(old, this.listPendingTraject));
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
}
```

This way, when you add items, it will animate them and slide the old ones down (Since you mentioned you wanted the top item to be the new one)

Note: I have to test this later, I wrote this on the fly

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter, create a custom method that accepts `PendingTrajectPOJO` as parameter, then update your `listPendingTraject`

Example:

```
public void addNewItem(PendingTrajectPOJO p) {
    listPendingTraject.add(p);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I would caution against using `notifyDataSetChanged()` and use `notifyItemInserted()` instead. Or better yet, use `DiffUtil`. See: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render#scrollable_lists